# Iptables LOG causes No chain/target/match error

Tags: iptables

I have used the following commands to build a chain in iptables:

```
iptables -N logaborted
iptables -A logaborted -j LOG
```

However, whenever this is run I get the following error:
`iptables: No chain/target/match by that name`

If I change `LOG` to any other target it starts working. The man page says nothing about this being deprecated and all the examples I have seen have LOG working, so why does it not work if I even dare to include the word `LOG` in my table?

Comment: What is your Linux distribution and kernel version?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04, kernel version 4.9, iptables 1.6.1

Comment: That is not a normal Ubuntu 18.04 kernel version. Exacty what kernel version? Where did you get it?

Comment: My team has a custom version we have been editing. I think thats the base version we used, but that was before my time.

Comment: Well, that's a new one. I've never heard of anybody doing that; it makes very little sense. (There are rare circumstances where it makes sense to replace the distribution kernel, but it generally doesn't make sense to do so as a matter of course.) You're going to have to chat with whoever built the kernel, then, or go back to the distribution kernel.

Comment: Check /boot/config-4.9.* for "CONFIG_NF_LOG_IPV4=m" or "CONFIG_NF_LOG_IPV4=y"; if not there, then your kernel is built without support for the LOG target.